# IOException lacking in detail - 403 Error

Tags: java, web-crawler, ioexception

Thing is: I have a webcrawler framework, and independent modules that implement this framework. All of these modules capture news from news specific websites.

In the framework there are 2 unpredictable errors which are: IOException, and SocketTimeoutException. For obvious reasons (The website may be offline, and/or under maintenance)

Thing is: In a specific website [(THIS one)](http://www.agoramt.com.br/) I get random IOExceptions all the time. I tried predicting it, but I still don't know why I'm getting this error.

I figured it was from bombing it with requests during test phase. It is not, since in 2 or 3 days without sending another requisition it still throws me the error.

**In a nutshell:** The site do not require authentication, and it randomly throws 403. RANDOMLY

Since 403 can be multiple different errors, I'd like to see what is the specific problem with my application.

If I could get which 403 it i, I could try and work around it. (403.1, 403.2, ..., 403.n)

```
//If you guys want the code, it's a basic Jsoup get. 
//(I have also tried it with native API, 
//and still get the same random 403 errors)

//Note that I also tried it with no redirection, and still get the error
Document doc = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.agoramt.com.br/")
    .timeout(60000)
    .followRedirects(true)
    .get();

//You may criticize about the code. But this specific line is the one 
//that throws the error. And it doesn't randomly do that to other 3k
//site connections. That's why I want to get the specifics from the 403
```

Comment: 403 means access is forbidden to you. What more reason do you need?

Comment: So why does it randomly thows this error?

Comment: Ah, I see. The issue is *random.* For the exact same URL? Do you see any clustering in time? Have you tried crawling from a different source IP address, or better yet, a complete different netblock?

Comment: It is random for that url, which is the homepage. And it is also random for other URLS within the same domain. And yes, I have tried from home (Windows 7, Debian), from work (Ubuntu), and also used a Mac from a friend. All of them from different places altogether. I have tried using different OS, and different IPs. That's why I ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A server may return a 403 on a whim. You are not expected to resolve this on your end except to respect the server's wishes not to let you in. You may try to read the response body for details provided by the server, but that's probably all you'll get. The 403.*n* error codes you are looking for, I believe, is an **IIS**-specific feature and the site you pointed out seems to be serving with **nginx**, so don't expect to get those.

If your webcrawler *randomly* gets a 403 but a regular web browser (from the same IP) *never* gets a 403 then the best I could suggest is for you to make your webcrawler request headers look *exactly* like what a regular web browser would send. Whether that is proper behavior for a polite webcrawler is a different discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In the design of a webcrawler, unexpected outages and error codes should be accounted for.

Keep a queue of sites that had a failure last time so that after a period of time, the webcrawler can retry the request.

Answer (score 0):

What the problem may be, is that there is a folder that you can get to, your program wants to read all the files on the site, but the webserver gives a 403 error, and will probably kill the socket.
This is what i'm thinking, without code, I can't tell its a programmatical error or just the configuration of the webserver.

Comment: I do know what a 403 is. And I did explain it in the question. I cannot predict the 403, as it randomly throws it. It isn't authentication problem as well, as the website don't require a login to show the news.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a faulty internet connection at the site, it could have code to try to stop spiders.  There could be a weird proxy server in the way.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try adding index.php to the end (or what ever the main homepage for the site is.. index.html, etc..)

I am unsure if this will help solve your problem however. I use a Connection class that I found somewhere, which basicly says as one of the posts above said (emulates the Headers of a web browser, so say... it appears like it is coming from FireFox, instead of what ever the java default is).

I guess it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

To piggy-back on what a couple others have said, is it possible your crawler is being recognized and treated as a network scanner or penetration tool?

Answer (score 0):

I have little idea what Jsoup is, but I suggest you read up on [HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29). This method will allow you to read the error document. Access to the header fields of the error document should be possible after a failed connection as well, the way you usually access header fields. Together, these two (body and header) will provide you with all the information which the server supplies.